# Xamarin Android Archieve is showing Empty

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to create apk file using Xamarin in Visual Studio. I change build type to Release and I open the Archieve but I cant see anything in this screen. Help me please. [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGFpR.png)

Comment: This is the archive page (where all of the already created archives are). In order for you to have an archive there, you need to archive your build first. Have you done it? Right-click on the project and then "Archive..."?

Answer (score 0):

You need to archive your app fist then you can see those archive in the [Archive Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows#the-archive-manager).

There are detailed steps about how to archive the app in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows#archive-for-publishing):

Right-click the `project` in `Solution` Explorer and select the `Archive`... context menu item:

[image]